# Every continuous function must be constant?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Prove that every continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}_{Za}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{Eu}$ must be constant, where $\mathbb{R}_{Za}$ represents the set $\mathbb{R}$ with the Zariski topology ($\{U\subseteq{\mathbb{R}}|U=\emptyset$ or $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus{S}$ for some $S\subseteq{\mathbb{R}}\}$) and $\mathbb{R}_{Eu}$ represents $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology.

Comment: The definition of the Zariski topology is wrong. The Zariski topology in $\mathbb{R}$ coincides with the cofinite topology which is defined by
$\tau_Z=\{U\in \mathbb{R} | \mathbb{R}\setminus U \textrm{ is finite} \}$.

Comment: The error pointed out by @RicardoCorreadaSilva is a serious one, amounting to imposing the discrete topology in the domain of $f$, which makes the claim (every continuous function is constant) false.  Since nothing has happened in the last five days to fix the inconsistency, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is not constant, then there exists $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. Define $\epsilon=\frac{|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|}{2}$ and notice that $A_1=(f(x_1)-\epsilon,f(x_1)+\epsilon)$ and $A_2=(f(x_2)-\epsilon,f(x_2)+\epsilon)$ are disjoint open sets, hence $f^{-1}(A_1)$ and $f^{-1}(A_2)$ are also open disjoint sets, but the definition of open sets in the cofinite topology implies that $\mathbb{R}\setminus f^{-1}(A_1)$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus f^{-1}(A_2)$ are finite. Notice now that $\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus f^{-1}(A_1)\right)\cup\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus f^{-1}(A_2)\right)=\mathbb{R}$, which is an contradiction because $\mathbb{R}$ is not finite.